# Would asking for a gear specific lesson be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Just want to make sure I'm following the rules here. There doesn't seem to be any "lesson" tag, so I figured I'd ask first.

I have a Korg Krome 88 keyboard, and coming from the piano, I find it quite vast. Although I currently take lessons from a keyboard instructor, we don't have the same exact gear.

What I'd like to do is perhaps pay for an hour (or whatever), if I could find someone with good knowledge of this keyboard - I'd like to learn things like splitting / layering etc. There's a ton of manuals and videos, but I'd much prefer a one on one. Thinking a Skype video thing would be perfect.

Would this be an acceptable question for music.stackexchange?

Answer (score 6):

Not at all.  This site is for specific questions, not soliciting services.  If you ask in the chatroom, it's possible someone might want to help, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the info. In general, would you have any advice on the best place to solicit for paid services? Craigslist creeps me out, but that's about the only place I can think of.

Comment: @MikeHildner There are dozens of sites like that--they are all quite Googlable, so I'm not going to buzz-market for any of them here. Even a search for "piano lessons" will turn most of them up.

Comment: @NReilingh - Thank you for your comment. I apologize for not being clear, but I am not looking for "piano lessons" - as stated in my original post, I already have an instructor. What I am looking for is someone who is very familiar with the the Korg Krome 88 and might like to trade some of their time for money. Now I know that this is not the place to ask, but I wasn't sure where to ask the question. Perhaps I'll ask the manufacturer or Sweetwater. I do apologize for any confusion or ignorance on my part.

Comment: @MikeHildner I would still recommend a similar place. The two sites I was thinking of are takelessons and skillpages -- these are essentially directories of experts categorized by field and geographic location. You could probably search for people with music production or electronic music specialty to find someone with in-depth knowledge of your keyboard.

Comment: @MikeHildner try to ask in our chat room. We'll answer it.

Comment: Just thought I'd follow up in case anyone is looking for something similar. What I ended up doing is going to the Korg forum, found a person that appeared to be an expert, contacted him privately, and asked if he'd be willing to do a lesson. That worked. Paid via PayPal and we did the lesson over Skype (with video). Very cool as he's in Romania and I'm in the US. Anyway, I got what I was looking for. Thanks to all who all who answered / commented.